# Calculate linear trend in each grid cell

Tags: python, grid, linear-regression, python-xarray

I have an `xarray` dataset of the dimensions `time=350`, `xc=432`, `yc=432` that contains data on sea ice concentration (variable `ice_conc`). I want to calculate the linear trend in each grid cell and create a trend map. I have tried using `numpy.polyfit`:

```py
x=np.linspace(1,350, num=350) #number of days in dataset

y=[ds.ice_conc] #ice concentration variable in the dataset

trend = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: expected 1D or 2D array for y

The variable `ice_conc` is a 3D array with `time`, `xc`, `yc`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to add more information with regards to the variable `ds`. As the error states, `y` needs to be a 1D or 2D `array`, but as you mention, `ds.ice_conc` is a 3D array, so `np.polyfit(...)` won't work. What are you trying to fit `x` against?

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your comment. ds is the name of my xarray dataset and ice_conc is the variable sea ice concentration that has the dimension time, xc, yc. I want to make a trend map, so I thought I needed to fit x (time=350) against the sea ice concentration variable that is a 3d array. I have read many examples on how to calculate linear regression but I can't seem to find any info on how to calculate it on each grid cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a xarray.Dataset already, you could simply use [xarray.Dataset.polyfit](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.polyfit.html)!

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some example data.
tsize = 10
xsize = 2
ysize = 2
data = np.ones((tsize, xsize, ysize)) * np.nan
data[:,0,0] = np.linspace(0, 10, tsize)
data[:,1,0] = np.logspace(0, 1, tsize)
data[:,0,1] = np.logspace(1.5, 0.5, tsize)
data[:,1,1] = np.linspace(40, 10, tsize)

# Put the data in a xarray.Dataset.
ds = xr.Dataset({"data": (["time", "x", "y"], data)})

# Apply polyfit.
result = ds.polyfit(dim = "time", deg = 1)

# The polyfit coefficients can be accessed like this.
a = result.data_polyfit_coefficients.sel(degree=1, x=0, y=0).values
b = result.data_polyfit_coefficients.sel(degree=0, x=0, y=0).values
```

The we could make a graph like this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(xsize, ysize, sharex=True)
fig.set_size_inches(8, 8)
xs = np.arange(tsize)
for x in ds.x:
    for y in ds.y:
        ax = axs[y,x]
        a = result.data_polyfit_coefficients.sel(degree=1, x=x, y=y).values
        b = result.data_polyfit_coefficients.sel(degree=0, x=x, y=y).values
        ax.scatter(xs, data[:, x, y], marker="*", 
                    c="tab:blue", label="original data")
        ax.plot(xs, a * xs + b, c="tab:orange", label=f"{a:.1f} * x + {b:.1f}")
        ax.legend()
        ax.grid()
        ax.set_facecolor("lightgray")
        ax.set_title(f"({x.values}, {y.values})")
```

[image: Polyfit applied to all four pixels in our dataset.]

Comment: Hi Bert! thanks for your answer!! I tried using xarray dataset polyfit on my dataset, but I get the following error: TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc lstsq_n :( :( :(

Comment: ok, i cant really help you with that based on just this info. You might have to adjust some things from my example to match it with your specific case, e.g. maybe your dimensions have different names than "time", "x" and "y".

Comment: I tried using polyfit on my variable ice_conc, which produces a new dataset with polyfit_coefficients, but the result doesn't seem right. Only producing -0.0 data and NaN.
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:               (degree: 1, yc: 432, xc: 432)
Coordinates:
  * degree                (degree) int64 0
  * yc                    (yc) float64 5.388e+03 5.362e+03 ... -5.388e+03
  * xc                    (xc) float64 -5.388e+03 -5.362e+03 ... 5.388e+03
Data variables:
    polyfit_coefficients  (degree, yc, xc) float64 -0.0 -0.0 -0.0 ... nan nan

Comment: Is there an approach that would provide significance values for the trend?